# Rails 4 ajax-request with form_tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm developing simple web-interface service, which interracts with database and has possibility to filter items by parameters.
Here is the example of code:

config/routes.rb

```
resources :list_items do
    collection do
      get 'filter'
    end
end
```

app/views/list_items/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(filter_list_items_path, method: 'get') do %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:some_parameter) %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Filter', remote: true %>
<% end %>

<table>  
  <%= render @list_items %>
</table>
```

partial app/views/list_items/_list_item.erb

```
<tr class="<%= cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even') %>" id="listElement">
  <td><%= list_item.attributes[:path] %></td>
</tr>
```

app/controllers/list_items_controller.rb

```
def filter
  @list_items ||= filter_items(params) #get @list_items array, according to params
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

app/views/list_items/filter.js.erb

```
$('#listElement').html('<%= escape_javascript render(@list_items) %>');
```

When I input data to text_field and press 'Filter' button, it calls filter action in list_items controller. I expect only table content would be refreshed, but instead of that it throws error `ActionController::UnknownFormat`.

P.S. when I add line `format.html { redirect_to list_items_url }` inside `respond_to` block, it doesn't throw errors and not apply filter.

I'm confused with rails, please clarify what I'm doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the form is submitting to the html format which is the default format in Rails, thats why the `format.html` is responding however since it returns html not javascript nothing happens.

You are getting the `UnknownFormat` error because in your action, you are only accepting `format.js` in the `respond_to` block.

To fix this, try changing your form to the following:

```
<%= form_tag(filter_list_items_path(format: :js), method: 'get', remote: true) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:some_parameter) %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Filter' %>
<% end %>
```

In the above code we are telling rails to explicitly submit the form to the `js` format, so this will generate a route with a `.js` postfix, also instead of putting the `remote` indicator on the submit button,  the correct way is to have it on the form tag.

Comment: Seems it works! The right way was so close ) Thank you